# Noun for people not yet confirmed as alive, or dead

Tags: word-request

In Italian, *disperso* (whose plural is *dispersi*) is a noun used for every person that is not yet confirmed as alive, or dead. The closer English word I can think is *missing* which is an adjective, and which I always heard as in *missing in action*.

Is there a noun that can be used for all the people missing after an accident, or a natural event?

Comment: I've heard "Schrödinger's People", but, of course, one can use it in a humorous context only, not when it's about real people and real disasters.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Missing* is probably the closest, or *unaccounted for*. Sometimes, one might say *assumed dead*, depending on context. Three days after an earthquake, for instance, when the chances of successful rescue are slim, then *assumed dead*, or *presumed dead* will often be used to describe those still unaccounted for.

Comment: Also, as you say, *unaccounted for* works too.

Comment: @MarkBeadles: Quite :)

Comment: In the first case, would you say "The missings are not anymore missing?"

Comment: @kiamlaluno: I suspect you would never hear that in anything resembling formal writing (i.e. a news report). If you said that among friends, you would likely be understood.

Comment: *The Missing*....that's gotta be a movie title.

Comment: Yep...http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Missing